# Buttons with Equal Width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons in a vertical `LinearLayout`. Is it possible to make them the same width, ideally as wide as the widest text?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="codeguru.swiss.MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newTournament"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/newTournament" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/loadTournament" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tried using layout_weight ?

Comment: @SachinG Yes. Since the `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` is set to `vertical`, the `layout_weight` applies to the *height* of the children.

Comment: @Downvoters **I don't know for what you downvoted this question. This question sounds good to me**.

Comment: I edited my answer what you are expecting you just see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTournament"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newTournament" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loadTournament" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your code your are using wrap_content so buttons will take space as per the content. So if you want two buttons to be same length then you must give the buttons width to fill parents width.

Comment: Does not fit to `ideally as wide as the widest text` criteria. This will instead make buttons be as wide parent's width.

Comment: @SachinG A small tweak fixes that by setting the parent's width to "wrap_content".

Answer (score 1):

After asking this question, I found that I could use a `TableLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

use this...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTournament"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/loadTournament" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

     <Button
    android:id="@+id/newTournament"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/newTournament" />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

      <Button
    android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loadTournament" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is more complicated than necessary. Why is each button inside a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the layout width evenly like this...

Below i have used the weights it will allocate the total weight and you can set the total weights into each elements I show how it will take the places you just refer my design picture

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I need two buttons of the same with inside a LinearLayout that is oriented vertically.

Comment: In above i have used the horizontal concept the you can replace the vertical that's it you can get your answer

Comment: I don't see how your solution will give the answer I am looking for. Can you give a simpler example with only two buttons?

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEnable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enable"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDisable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Disable"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lock"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSetPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Set Password"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </View>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWipeData"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Wipe Data"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkWipeExtStorage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Also Wipe External Storage"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClearPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Clear Password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLockTask"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lock Task" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain how your code answers my question. Also, is all of this XML really necessary to answer the question?

Answer (score -3):

Use layout_alignRight and layout_alightLeft:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newTournament"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/newTournament"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/loadTournament" />
```

Comment: This would only work if the Button's parent was a RelativeLayout

Answer (score -3):

you can use `layout_weight` for this . just use like below,

```
    <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newTournament"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/newTournament"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loadTournament"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loadTournament"
   />
```

Comment: Since the LinearLayout has an orientation of "vertical", the weight applies the the height of the each child, not the width.

Comment: @Code-Guru I have just copy your code and make the desired changes. You have put the `orientation` "vertical".

Comment: you are asking question or just checking people's technical knowledge.

Comment: Did you test the desired changes to check that they have an effect on the width of the buttons?

Comment: I am asking a question and stating that your proposed solution doesn't work (along with the reasons why).

Comment: sorry -Code-Guru It's my mistake. I should have to test it first.I have update my ans and also tested it.